# How to select window in ratpoison without it changing frame

Tags: ratpoison

When you use select in ratpoison, sometimes window changes frame. I would like it to always stay in the same frame. Is there any way to achieve that ? I don't want windows jumping around. This depends on the current layout.

I use standard windows.sh shell script that creates ratmenu with window list. 
Using command next and previous is not an option because they switch windows only in current frame ...